# Read-only NTFS flash drive refuses to format

Tags: ntfs, readonly, file-format

I have this SanDisk Cruzer Edge where it's a write-protected NTFS partition that I got from my dad as I needed a flash drive.

I tried using GParted, didn't work, I saw something online that used the terminal, which didn't work.

I use Ubuntu Unity 22.04, which might be problematic but it does have most if not all GNOME utilities.

List of what has been attempted:

- formatting via GParted
- formatting via terminal

What the drive contains is basically a bootleg installer for either Windows XP or Windows 7 that is Legacy-only. Which is in Russian.

What do I do? thanks very much.

please I beg for help I have only used Linux for about a year properly and I am very much lost

Comment: Wipe it with  `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX`? Where `X` is the drive letter.If that does not work, look for a physical switch on the drive.

Comment: it spewed this out: ```dd: failed to open '/dev/sdc': Read-only file system```

Comment: You can analyze the problem according to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) to a answer at AskUbuntu, and if you are lucky you can find a solution.

Comment: Does `blockdev --setrw /dev/sdX` help? Most likely the drive is already dead / bricked though.

Comment: Neither did help. Thanks anyway, something else?